# The physics of a dog sled --- how much power or energy over time?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction, power, estimation

I'm looking for some equations that govern the physics of a dog sled. Let's say we have 8 dogs pulling a sled. Each dog provides a force of F, the tractive effort. The sled weighs W and there's a coefficient of friction between the skis and the snow.

What I want is an equation that can tell me how much energy is spent over time (power) in order to keep the sled moving at some constant speed.

The "normal" example of this sort of thing is for trains pulling a load. Well, they all involve rolling resistance. In my case, there are no wheels. I do not know if a coefficient of friction can just be substituted in the place of rolling resistance. I remember from my physics classes that anti-lock brakes do not depend on the weight of the car due to some clever thing in rolling resistance, so I am wary of this. It seems to me that the weight of the sled will directly affect the friction it has between the skis and the snow.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there is some frictional force $f$ that you need to equal to maintain a constant speed $v$ for the sled.

The power requires is the force time the velocity $fv$ and so the energy required in a time $\Delta t$ is $fv\Delta t$.

The problem is the frictional force in that there are many components to this force.
The air resistance will depend on a number of factors including the speed of the sled, the density of the air, the frontal area of the sled, the "shape" of the sled and its contents ie a measure of how aerodynamic or not it is etc.  The Wikipedia article [Drag Coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_coefficient) shows how air resistance can be quantified.
Assuming that the dynamic friction $\mu$ between the sled runners and the snow is constant then the frictional force will be $\mu mg$ where $m$ is the mass of the sled and its contents which will obviously increase if you ride on the sled.